# CKEditor destroys the widget on drag and drop

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor's widget functionality to create my own widget with a jquery component there. However when the widget is dragged and dropped it gets destroyed and all the state in the jquery component gets lost.
Can this behavior be avoided? Is it configurable? Why it is required (maybe the CKEditor team can answer this)?

Answer (score 8):

It is true that the widget is destroyed (and re-initialized) during drag and drop, this behavior can't be avoided.

How do you link your jQuery component with the widget object? What does your widget definition look like? (It is the object that you pass in the `editor.widgets.add()` call). Do you use `Widget.setData()` / How do you set this jQuery component as widget data?

If it's hard for you to answer these questions, you might just copy paste here the source code of your widget instance (open the browser's developer tools and look for an element with the `data-cke-widget-id` attribute - do not confuse with source mode view in CKEditor). Paste it with the whole content.

Widgets store their data in the `data-cke-widget-data` HTML attribute. A blind guess would be that you either do not set the data correctly on the widget or when it is stringified and then parsed back, it doesn't handle the jQuery object properly. Maybe you could initialize your jQuery component using `widget.definition.init` and keep the data as a plain object (`Widget.setData`)?

You might also want to look to [CKEditor widget documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget) for more information.

Comment: So in general I have to store the current state using setData so I could restore it properly after recreation when the widget is drag and dropped, right?

Comment: Yes, `Widget.setData` should save everything inside `data-cke-widget-data` attribute of widget's element and it should be available even after destroying the widget.

Comment: What can I do if the widget is more complex thing (i.e. jquery tree with nodes that can be expanded by the user. In this case when the widget is DnD I have to recreate the entire tree) ?

Comment: Maybe you could store the data somewhere else (a global controller or something) and keep only some kind of token that will reference it?